# Plugin Scripts no loading on options page

Tags: jquery, javascript, actions, wp-enqueue-script

I've got this in my main php file, but the scripts aren't loading

```
function class_table_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'JavaScript1', plugins_url('js/wcs.js'), array() );
    wp_register_script( 'JavaScript1', plugins_url('js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js'), array('jquery') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'class_table_scripts' );
```

I've never tried to use JS or JQuery on the options page before, this is my first go. Any pointers on where I'm going wrong here?

---

EDIT:
Here's what finally worked for me:

```
function class_table_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'JavaScript1', plugins_url('js/wcs.js',__FILE__));
    wp_register_script( 'JQuery1', plugins_url('js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js',__FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'class_table_scripts' );
```

Comment: Please add your solution as a new answer to this question and accept it. Or this question will pop up ever once in a while, as the Community bot regards it unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I finally got it:

```
function class_table_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'JavaScript1', plugins_url('js/wcs.js',__FILE__));
    wp_register_script( 'JQuery1', plugins_url('js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js',__FILE__) );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'class_table_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey use admin_enqueue_scripts.
if you want to load a set of CSS and/or Javascript documents to all admin pages. You can do this from within your plugin or from your themes function file using **admin_enqueue_scripts**:

```
function class_table_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'JavaScript1', plugins_url('js/wcs.css'), array() );
    wp_enqueue_script('JavaScript1');
    wp_register_script( 'JavaScript1', plugins_url('js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js'), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_script('JavaScript1');
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'class_table_scripts' );
```

Comment: Answer is incomplete. Explain why the right hook to use is admin_enqueue_scripts please

Comment: This didn't do it for me. I did get it using `admin_init` tho. I updated with the code that finally worked.